# What is the difference between 'I will do it' vs 'Let me do it'?

Tags: will-would, let

I feel the following sentences sound similar meaning but still, we use them differently at a different situation. What is the reason for this?

1. **Let me show you around the city** *vs* **I will show you around the city**.
2. **Let me clean the dishes** *vs*  **I will clean the dishes**.
3. **I will check it** *vs* **let me check it**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- "I will..." is a certain statement of what you *will* do.
- "Let me..." is a *request* for someone to *allow you* to do something.

However, the latter isn't usually a question - it is more often than not used as a polite way to introduce something you are about to do, for example, "allow me to introduce myself" may be said before one introduces themself!

In your examples, the intent and result may well be the same, but "let me" is a polite way of stating your intent, whereas "I will" is a more forceful way of saying it.

Answer (score 1):

“Let me do X” is the first-person singular imperative. The imperative is an request or demand (depending on tone) to do X (in the second person) or allow someone else to do X (in the first or third person).

“I will do X” is the simple future tense, a statement of what you are going to do, without requesting or demanding permission.

Answer (score 0):

When the work involves another person or they don't like you to do the work, use "Let me". Otherwise you should use "I will".